# rails association for legacy data when foreign_key is string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, legacy

I have the unfortunate task of making some legacy data work with a rails ap. Some of the id fields are strings

```
:client_id => "30430"
```

But in postgres (which we’d prefer to use) the association query chokes because of the data type mismatch. Is there a way around this?

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: bigint = character varying LINE 1: ...ients" INNER JOIN "reservation" ON "clients"."id" = "reserva...   
No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

To be explicit, I'm looking for solutions that don't involve altering the underlying data (though that would be my first choice)

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought you could just write a migration to convert the column type to integer, which works with mysql but apparently not postgres:

https://makandracards.com/makandra/18691-postgresql-vs-rails-migration-how-to-change-columns-from-string-to-integer

Assuming your table is called products, the following should work:

```
change_column :products, :client_id, 'integer USING CAST(column_name AS integer)'
```

As the link states, any strings with a non numeric value will obviously give weird results, if not throw an error. And it's obviously worth trying out locally first.

Comment: sorry I can't change the data directly. But I have pushed that request up the chain of command...

Comment: I guess you could manually write out the associations - instead of belongs_to :client, write out a client method that returns the record with a matching string ID

Comment: Yes, but I actually also have Departure has many clients, through reservations.